# Correct Joomla language on Ajax external file

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

Basically I'm working on a custom code inside a Joomla based website and I'm using jQuery Ajax.

I also need to use Joomla language variables because it's a multilanguage website but seems like the Ajax files doesn't recognize the Joomla language tag.

I add to my Ajax files this code in the start

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', '/var/www/');

require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/framework.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('custom',JPATH_ROOT)
```

But there's no value on *$lang->getTag()* once the Ajax file process the request. And the Joomla JTEXT variable are untranslated.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please ask all of your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Save the language tag in a userState then you can get it in ajax file like:

```
//load the language
$lang         = Factory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_example', JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_example', $storedLanguageTag, true);
```

Comment: If you can offer support for Joomla questions, please extend your Stack Exchange account to include [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.